# How do I customize Windows 7 Open/Save dialogue?

Tags: windows-7, windows, gui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Customizing fast-access buttons on left-hand side of File->Open dialogue in most Windows programs](https://superuser.com/questions/253674/customizing-fast-access-buttons-on-left-hand-side-of-file-open-dialogue-in-most)

1. I want to add one or two "hot" places in the Open/Save dialogue.
2. I want to remove "library" and "network" icon from Open/Save dialogue.
3. Also, can I make ".JPG" as my top Save As choice?

[image]

Comment: I would tend to disagree. Its pulling from system locations. That does not mean that they are infintely customizable, or that you can even really change it (changing where my network is not something you ever want to do) but it should be possible.

Comment: I recommend you asking the 3rd part as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks, guys. Just thought it would be more convenient and user-friendly to include these features.

Comment: And plus, I don't think the tweakUI would work in Win7 anyway.