# remove default items from "Save as" dialog in explorer?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, desktop, desktop-customization

I'm having trouble figuring out how to remove the default items on the left side of the "Save as..." dialog in Windows.

[image]

I want only my favorites to be displayed, how can I remove the default items? I hate it to scroll each time all the way up (I have a much smaller window than on the screenshot) to just select "User Tracks" or anything else from favorites... :/

Comment: What actual trouble are you running into while removing them? What have you tried already?

Comment: Related: [Can I remove the locations/views from the Windows Explorer pane in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/21485/can-i-remove-the-locations-views-from-the-windows-explorer-pane-in-windows-7?rq=1)

Comment: I just can't find a way, no RMB options or anything, are those solutions tested on Windows 8? My backup disk hasn't arrived yet so I have no backup of my system.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Customizing fast-access buttons on left-hand side of File->Open dialogue in most Windows programs](http://superuser.com/questions/253674/customizing-fast-access-buttons-on-left-hand-side-of-file-open-dialogue-in-most) (related: [How do I customize Windows 7 Open/Save dialogue?](http://superuser.com/questions/315206/how-do-i-customize-windows-7-open-save-dialogue))  If the answers/info there don't help, let us know what didn't work for you and this question may be kept open  (since you _are_ using Windows 8).

Comment: Well the removel ibraries reg does work on the explorer window but not on the save as.. dialog... for all the other stuff, not really working (in my case?) and I have the normal windows 8, not Pro so I have no group policy editor.. :/

Comment: As for removing homegroup and favorites it's easy, but the case is I want to keep favorites because I can customize them to my will :D As for the solution for libraries.. well not a real solution but I have just hidden all the subitems from "libraries" but the libraries option is still there and taking up 50px at least.

Comment: Check the answers in http://superuser.com/questions/253674/customizing-fast-access-buttons-on-left-hand-side-of-file-open-dialogue-in-most again. :)

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/431902/144773 doesn't work too, no changes at all. (yep restarted my machine, which I never doo.. damn, had a uptime of 56 days xd)

Comment: There is no way to remove those locations.

Comment: well I just collapsed them for now ;f