# How can I replace the File Save Dialog in Photoshop CS5?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gui

I found the answer to this about a year ago, but I can't find it anymore.

What I am trying to do is replace the "File Save Dialog Legacy" that is used in Photoshop CS5 with the Windows 7 "FileOpenDialog".

I am using Windows 7 Home, so I do not have gpedit.msc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted a similar question with Opera somewhat recently, perhaps it will provide a useful answer?  I see many answers there that look like they may be helpful.

- [Customizing fast-access buttons on left-hand side of File->Open dialogue in most Windows programs](https://superuser.com/questions/253674/customizing-fast-access-buttons-on-left-hand-side-of-file-open-dialogue-in-most)

Also, in Adobe Photoshop CS4 Extended my dialogue shows a "Recent places" button (as pictured below).  Could you post a picture of yours from Adobe Photoshop CS5?

[image]

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same thing.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to edit the locations on the left using Regedit and following the instructions you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

But there *is* a Favorites button on the Open/Save dialogues in Photoshop (and it has been there for a long time, as far as I can remember).

Maybe you have missed it at the top-right corner?  You can see the screenshot that Randolph added to his answer.

It is more useful to have a separate collection of favourites to the system favourites, when doing graphics work, I think, but using the new Adobe Bridge integration is more useful.  Have you missed that too?

Comment: It's a different favorites button. It's deprecated and no longer points to the Windows 7 favorite locations.

Comment: @Josiah: So how could it be useful in any way, anyway?

Comment: It can't, and that's why I want to replace the dialog with the Windows 7 dialog rather than the legacy one.

Comment: @Josiah: I don't understand what you are saying, but you can add any location to the Favourites button on the top-right corner of the Open/Save dialogue box in Photoshop.